# A problem about chrome devltools javascript profiler flame graph, aggregated time is smaller than total time

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, devtools, flamegraph

aggregated time and  total time are underlined in the picture.
[devtool flame graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MkTQ.png)

what's the meaning of this circumstance?